# Javascript-Jquery form

Tags: javascript

I develop a basic form in HTML/JS.
I use javascript to check my fields. But they are only verifying when they are empty. How do I validate my form if the fields are correct or invalid if the fields are incorrect.

Maybe i need to complete my verifier function(). But how ? I am a little lost ;(

Thank you in advance !

JS :

```js
var regex = /[^a-zA-Z]/;
var regex2 = /[^a-zA-Z_]/;


$(document).ready(function () {

    var $nom = $('#name'),
        $prenom = $('#prenom'),
        $centre = $('#centre'),
        $magasin = $('#magasin'),
        $profil = $('#profil'),
        $date = $('#date'),
        $envoie = $('#envoie'),
        $erreur = $('#erreur'),
        $champ = $('.champ');

    /* FONCTION REGEX */

    $nom.keypress(function() {
        var color = regex.test(this.value) ? "red" : "green";
        $(this).css({
            borderColor: color,
            color: color
        });
    });


    $prenom.keypress(function() {
        var color = regex.test(this.value) ? "red" : "green";
        $(this).css({
            borderColor: color,
            color: color
        });
    });

    $profil.keypress(function() {
        var color = regex2.test(this.value) ? "red" : "green";
        $(this).css({
            borderColor: color,
            color: color
        });
    });

    /* AUTRES FONCTIONS */

    function verifier(champ) {
        if (champ.val() == "") {
            $erreur.css('display', 'block');
            champ.css({
                borderColor: 'red',
                color: 'red'
            });

        }
    }



    $envoie.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        verifier($nom);
        verifier($centre);
        verifier($magasin);
        verifier($profil);
        verifier($prenom);
        verifier($date);

    });




    $centre.keypress(function () {
        if($(this).val().length > 2){
            $(this).css({
                borderColor: 'red',
                color: 'red'
            });
        }
        else{
            $(this).css({
                borderColor: 'green',
                color: 'green'
            });
        }
    });

    $magasin.keypress(function () {
        if($(this).val().length > 2){
            $(this).css({
                borderColor: 'red',
                color: 'red'
            });
        }
        else{
            $(this).css({
                borderColor: 'green',
                color: 'green'
            });
        }
    });

    $("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        console.log("passage");
        if ($("#myForm input.invalid").length > 0) {
            $("#logs").text("fail !");
            return false;
        }
        $("#logs").text("success !")
        //return true; // laisse pour fonctionnement normal
        return false;
    });


});
```

Answer (score -1):

Validating fields can be a tricky process to fully write out yourself. I would highly recommend the [jQuery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin.

It works like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            fieldOne: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            fieldTwo: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="fieldOne">
    <input type="text" name="fieldTwo">
    <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok thanks you ProEvilz ! But it will work with my regex in rules ?

Comment: Not word for word no, but you can use regex with the validate plugin.

Comment: I don't know ! ;(